# Laravel Join returns duplicates data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Im trying to get top five players and I use join to get each players information base on personId, but my query returns duplicate data. I cant figure out why it duplicating the record, any help would be much appriciated. Thanks

```
DB::table('person_competition_statistics as pcs')
                    ->where('pcs.competitionId', $competitionId)
                    ->where('pcs.teamId', $teamId)
                    ->orderBy('pcs.sStealsAverage', 'desc')
                    ->rightJoin('players as player', 'pcs.personId', '=',  'player.personId')
                    ->select(['pcs.personId', 'pcs.sStealsAverage', 'player.firstName', 'player.familyName', 'player.playingPosition', 'player.image_thumb'])
                    ->take(5)
                    ->get();
```

Here is the result

```
#items: array:5 [▼
      0 => {#444 ▼
        +"personId": 29872
        +"sStealsAverage": 1.24
        +"firstName": "Rhys"
        +"familyName": ""
        +"playingPosition": ""
        +"image_thumb": ""
      }
      1 => {#438 ▼
        +"personId": 29872
        +"sStealsAverage": 1.24
        +"firstName": "Rhys"
        +"familyName": ""
        +"playingPosition": ""
        +"image_thumb": ""
      }
      2 => {#439 ▼
        +"personId": 29872
        +"sStealsAverage": 1.24
        +"firstName": "Rhys"
        +"familyName": ""
        +"playingPosition": "GRD"
        +"image_thumb": ""
      }
      3 => {#441 ▼
        +"personId": 29872
        +"sStealsAverage": 1.24
        +"firstName": "Rhys"
        +"familyName": ""
        +"playingPosition": "GRD"
        +"image_thumb": ""
      }
      4 => {#435 ▼
        +"personId": 29872
        +"sStealsAverage": 1.24
        +"firstName": "Rhys"
        +"familyName": ""
        +"playingPosition": "GRD"
        +"image_thumb": ""
      }
```

Comment: Add a `groupBy`.

Comment: Add a distinct and remove `playingPosition` else you will still have duplicates.

Comment: you can add group by

Comment: @SougataBose I've tried adding groupBy('pcs.personId') but return an error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db_nblmothership.pcs.sStealsAverage' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen your solution works but i need to return the players playingPosisiton

Comment: group by column should be placed in select clause .otherwise you will get this error .  @PenAndPapers

Comment: Then the GROUP BY will be needed: You have to either list every column from your result in the group by or apply a group function (MIN, MAX, AVG, etc) to your column to create an ANSI compliant query

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used **unique** to return unique personId and **array_slice** to get the top 5, below is my code.

```
$spg = DB::table('person_competition_statistics as pcs')
                    ->where('pcs.competitionId', $competitionId)
                    ->where('pcs.teamId', $teamId)
                    ->orderBy('pcs.sStealsAverage', 'desc')
                    ->join('players as player', 'pcs.personId', '=',  'player.personId')
                    ->select(['pcs.personId', 'pcs.sStealsAverage', 'player.firstName', 'player.familyName', 'player.playingPosition', 'player.image_thumb'])
                    ->get();

$spg = $spg->unique('personId');
$spg = array_slice($spg->values()->all(), 0, 5, true);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use groupBy with your unique Id with out your tablename Like

```
 DB::table('person_competition_statistics as pcs')
                    ->where('pcs.competitionId', $competitionId)
                    ->where('pcs.teamId', $teamId)
                    ->orderBy('pcs.sStealsAverage', 'desc')
                    ->rightJoin('players as player', 'pcs.personId', '=',  'player.personId')
                    ->select(['pcs.personId', 'pcs.sStealsAverage', 'player.firstName', 'player.familyName', 'player.playingPosition', 'player.image_thumb'])
                    ->take(5)
                    ->groupBy('personId')
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using raw SQL :

```
    $sql = " SELECT t.personId, t.sStealsAverage, 
        player.firstName, player.familyName,
        player.playingPosition, player.image_thumb
  FROM
  (
      SELECT pcs.personId, pcs.sStealsAverage
      FROM person_competition_statistics AS pcs
      WHERE pcs.competitionId = $competitionId
      AND pcs.teamId = $teamId
      ORDER BY pcs.sStealsAverage DESC
      LIMIT 5
  ) t
  LEFT players AS player ON (t.personId = player.personId)";
  $result = DB::select($sql);
```

Comment: still dont work, it returns duplicate data @NazmulHasan